Is there a way to use "equals to" insted of "includes" in javascript
Is there a way to use "equals to" insted of "includes" in javascript
i have this code language translate
I have an Arabic code. If I write ABC, it shows 1. If I write ABCD, it is supposed to show 2, but it does not show up because of includes i want to use == insted of includes.
My JS
<script>
  function translate(e){

  while(trdn.includes("speak")){
  trdn = trdn.replace("speak", "talar");
  }

while(trdn.includes("speak1")){
  trdn = trdn.replace("speak1", "talar1");
  }

while(trdn.includes("speak2")){
  trdn = trdn.replace("speak2", "talar2");
  }

}
</script>

i have already tried
while(trdn == ("speak")){
  trdn = trdn.replace("speak", "talar");

my whole html
<div class="container">
           <textarea name="" id="input" cols="30" rows="10" class="input" placeholder="input here"></textarea>
           <div id="output" class="output">
               <span style="color:lightslategray;">translated text</span>
           </div>
       </div>

<script>
 var trdn;
var ttsToggle = false;
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[4];
document.getElementById("input").onkeyup = function(e){
 trdn = " " + document.getElementById("input").value;
 translate(e);
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = trdn;
 if(ttsToggle == true){
   setTimeout(function(){
     msg.text = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
     window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
   },1000)
 }
}
/*document.getElementById("ttsToggle").onmousedown = function(e){
 if(ttsToggle == false){
   ttsToggle = true;
   document.getElementById("ttsToggle").innerHTML = "toggle_on";
 }
 else{
   ttsToggle = false;
   document.getElementById("ttsToggle").innerHTML = "toggle_off";
 }
}*/
 </script>

<script>
 function translate(e){

 while(trdn.includes("speak")){
 trdn = trdn.replace("speak", "talar");
 }

while(trdn.includes("speak1")){
 trdn = trdn.replace("speak1", "talar1");
 }

while(trdn.includes("speak2")){
 trdn = trdn.replace("speak2", "talar2");
 }

}
</script>


What is trdn? Is it a set or a list? What is its type?

I wonder if this isn't an XY problem. Why exactly do you want to use == here at all? What are you trying to achieve?

Note that while(trdn.includes("speak")) { trdn = trdn.replace("speak", "talar"); } is equivalent to trdn = trdn.replaceAll("speak", "talar").

The edit doesn't make it clear why you need to do "equals". It just adds more code with no real explanation for why you're showing it or what you think it shows.

includes is an Array method. Could try trdn.indexOf('word') > -1, but withreplaceAll as Amadan suggests you wouldn't need to check if it exists, just run it and if the word doesn't exist then there's nothing to replace.

@l3l_aze trdn is a string. If it was an array, the trdn.replace() would be throwing an error. String#includes() exists

Note that the first loop will replace the “speak” in “speak1” and “speak2” with talar.  You can handle the more specific keys first (speak1/speak2) to avoid that if needed.

No
The ==/=== operator is for equality comparison.
There is no operator overloading, so an equality operator (or others) cannot change their meaning.
